# Jest - Snapshot test fail after adding '</React.Fragment>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am receiving the error below after running Jest. I dont have much experience using Jest so hoping someone can please provide information on why this test is failing.

Results:
**Jest test result:**

```
- Snapshot
+ Received
- <span
-   className="icon icon-dismiss size-2x "
-   style={
-     Object {
-       "color": "inherit",
+ <Fragment>
+   <span
+     className="icon icon-dismiss size-2x "
+     style={
+       Object {
+         "color": "inherit",
+       }
      }
-   }
-   title=""
- />
+     title=""
+   />
+ </Fragment>

  26 |     };
  27 |     const wrapper = shallow(<Icon {...props} />);
> 28 |     expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
     |                             ^
  29 |   });
  30 | });
```

Here is the test file:
**Test File**

**Component.spec.jsx**

```
describe('Snapshot test - <Icon />', () => {
  it('renders Icon correctly in clean state', () => {
    const props = {
      icon: 'dismiss',
    };
    const wrapper = shallow(<Icon {...props} />);
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  it('renders Icon correctly when colour provided', () => {
    const props = {
      icon: 'dismiss',
      color: '#000000',
    };
    const wrapper = shallow(<Icon {...props} />);
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

});
```

Here is the component file:
**component.js**

```
class Icon extends React.PureComponent<IconProps> {
  render() {
    const {
      className, icon, size, colour, style, title,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {icon === 'spinner' ? <LoadingSpinnerSmall /> : (
          <span
            title={title}
            className={`${css.icon} ${css[`icon-${icon}`]} ${css[`size-${size}`]} ${className}`}
            style={{ color: colour === null ? 'initial' : colour, ...style }}
          />
        )
      }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Icon;
```

Comment: This happens when you change your test and run the tests  after the last time you ran those tests. Try deleting your previous snapshots and then running the tests.

Comment: @AtinSingh I added '</React.Fragment>' to the component file and ever since then the test has failed.

Comment: Yes that's why it failed because your component changed. See the error. It says `received + <Fragment>` try deleting your old snapshot and then try running the tests.

Comment: Thanks - I will try that

Comment: Do tell me if it worked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snapshot match test result

```
- Snapshot
+ Received
- <span
-   className="icon icon-dismiss size-2x "
-   style={
-     Object {
-       "color": "inherit",
+ <Fragment>
+   <span
+     className="icon icon-dismiss size-2x "
+     style={
+       Object {
+         "color": "inherit",
+       }
      }
-   }
-   title=""
- />
+     title=""
+   />
+ </Fragment>
```

This shows your component has extra code from the previous time you ran the tests which is the `<Fragment>` opening tag and `</Fragment>` closing tag.

To solve this just delete your old snapshots and re run your tests.